# Combine 2 tables which doesn't have any relationship

Tags: sql

I have couple of tables like below-

**Table1:**

```
A B C D <<Columns
1 2 3 4 <<single row
```

**Table2:**

```
W X Y Z << Columns
5 6 7 8 << Single row
```

I want to combine these 2 tables such a way that it will give me following result

**Result:**

```
P Q R S << Column headers
1 2 3 4 << row from table1
5 6 7 8 << row from table2
```

Expected result will have column headers as P, Q, R, S and row from table1 and row from table2

How to achieve this using SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **UNION ALL** will not eliminate duplicates
- In set operations (UNION / INTERSECT / EXCEPT) the aliases are taken from the first query (Currently I'm aware of only one exception- Hive requires the aliases to be the same for all queries - I consider this as a bug)

---

```
select  A as P, B as Q, C as R, D as S
from    table1

union all

select  W,X,Y,Z
from    table2
```

---

```
+---+---+---+---+
| p | q | r | s |
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

---

table2 with 3 Columns

```
select  B as Q, C as R, D as S
from    table1

union all

select  X,Y,Z
from    table2
```

---

```
+---+---+---+
| q | r | s |
+---+---+---+
| 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 |
+---+---+---+
```

or

```
select  A as P, B as Q, C as R, D as S
from    table1

union all

select  null,X,Y,Z
from    table2
```

---

```
+--------+---+---+---+
|   p    | q | r | s |
+--------+---+---+---+
| 1      | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| (null) | 6 | 7 | 8 |
+--------+---+---+---+
```

Comment: What will happen when Table2 has only 3 columns - X, Y, Z? Should I use UNION ALL in this case too?

Comment: Thanks for quick response.

Answer (score 1):

_Updated to be more strict and more complete, thanks to @AntDC (and @Matt) and @Dudu Markovitz__

Use `UNION` with aliases, like this:

```
SELECT A AS P, B AS Q, C AS R, D AS S
FROM table1
UNION
-- or UNION ALL if you want to keep duplicate rows
SELECT W, X, Y, Z
FROM table2
```

Comment: I think you only need to alias the columns in the first select.
Also - you will need UNION ALL if the rows are identical.

Comment: @AntDC I don't agree: it'll keep original col names for the 2nd select, so not giving the expected result.

Comment: @AntDC ' suggestions works in mysql http://rextester.com/TMCWM42152, sql server http://rextester.com/LIQDCM48260, PostrgeSQL http://rextester.com/DZZF66752 pretty sure it works in Oracle and generally every platform. Even if you leave the aliases which is find the OP did not state to remove duplicate rows so I would also agree that you probably need `UNION ALL`

Comment: @AntDC Sorry: you're right. The funny thing is that I never knew this "tolerance", maybe introduced later than my initial SQL skills, that are from 1990!